# How to get override the WP Admin Syndication feed limit for a custom feed?

Tags: posts, feed, dashboard

I need to override the setting in the WP Admin for the number of recent posts in the Syndication settings under General -> Admin.

I'm using the following code, which gets all posts, but I don't need that many. Can someone tell me how to retrieve 50 posts?

```
function no_limits_for_feed( $limits ) {
    return '';
}

add_filter( 'post_limits', 'no_limits_for_feed' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no normal filter. It's a [`filter_ref_array`](http://wpseek.com/apply_filters_ref_array/).

```
// Use this to alter your limit:
add_filter( 'post_limits', create_function( '$a', "return 'LIMIT $start, 10';" ) );
```

---

**EDIT**

After I saw that this got marked as solution, I want to show you a more "best practice"-approach:

```
function alter_feed_post_limits( $limits )
{
    return " LIMIT 0,50";
}
add_action( 'post_limits', 'alter_feed_post_limits' );
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me. I'm getting 0 results after adding that line. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at the link. I just gave you a starting point.

Comment: Actually there is nothing special about such filter, the way it is called is merely internal stuff and you add to it like usual.